# OOP programming

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

i have a class say A that has a protected method say methodA(), then i extend a class B from class A and do not override the methodA(); then i created a class C  and extend it with class B and i want to override the methodA();

how can i do so with out overriding methodA(); in class B,

```
class A{
   public funciton methodA():void {
      // do stuff
   }
}

class B extends A{
  //do stuff but not override the methodA

}

class C extends B{
   override public function methodA():void {
      // possible or not 
   }
}
```

is it possible  (i think not just want to confirm)

regards.

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: no no i was trying it in action script 3

Comment: Why didn't you just test this? Lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, And I think simple test helps you. I'm not familiar with your language syntax, but just override on same method name as in `A` in class `C`.